# How to merge two SVN branches with file renames and code modified?

Tags: svn

I have created a SVN  branch from particular revision number, let's say from branch 1.0 to 2.0

Now worked on both the branches.

1. Modified and Renamed some files into branch 2.0.
2. Worked on the same files (renamed in 2.0) in the branch 1.0.

Now I want to merge these two branches.  There are many files which have been modified and renamed in branch 2.0.  Please tell any tool to merge

Comment: Have you tried performing a merge with `svn merge` yourself yet?

Comment: no, I think it will not work.

Comment: Based upon what? You won't know until you try.